# How to find accelerometer input event file and write the file directly in android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

Can anybody tell me how to find the accelerometer input event file and write the file directly, in android? Is it possible on an android device?

**I am developing an application which will test another application for user activity recognition. My intention is that I want to set sensor in android device using my developing application. Can anybody give me a way of doing this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you're asking is how to capture accelerometer data and then write it to a file. If not, please let me know and I'll edit.

To capture the accelerometer data, you'll just implement the SensorEventListener interface and then register the exact Accelerometer sensor you want. A great tutorial on implementing the accelerometer into your code is [this one](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/).

To save to a file, just follow the Android Developer's official guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

A word of warning: saving accelerometer data will quickly create a lot of data. The accelerometer can easily fire its onSensorChanged() event 80 times in a couple of seconds.

Comment: I want to set mock sensor in android device .I want to set static data to accelrometer event file is it possible in android

Comment: The accelerometer returns three floats for each onSensorChanged() event. Just generate random sets on three floats if you want mock data. If you want real data, do the steps as i outlined above, then use the stored data as your mock data.

Comment: can you briefly tell how to set mock data in android device if u provide example it wiil hepful for me.I want to set mock sensor user is walking or driving statically the other application will use this sensor data will check the application